# AUC of logistic and ordinal model following multiple imputation using MICE (with R)

Tags: r, imputation, auc, r-mice

I am asking a question concerning the additive predictive benefit of the inclusion of a variable to a logistic and an ordinal model. I am using mice to impute missing covariates and am having difficulty finding ways to calculate the AUC and R squared of the pooled imputed models. Does anyone have any advice?

The summary readout only provides the term, estimate, std.error, statistic, df , p.value

Example code:

```
imputed_Data <- mice(Cross_sectional, m=10, predictorMatrix=predM, seed=500, method = meth)
Imputedreferecemodel <- with(imputed_Data, glm(Poor ~ age + sex + education + illness + injurycause, family = "binomial", na.action=na.omit) )
summary(pool(Imputedreferecemodel))
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`psfmi`](https://mwheymans.github.io/psfmi/articles/psfmi_mice.html) package in combination with `mice`. You could use the function `pool_performance` to measure performances for logistic regression, according to documentation:

> pool_performance Pooling performance measures for logistic and Cox
> regression models.

I use the `nhanes` dataset which is standard in `mice` to show you a reproducible example.

```r
# install.packages("devtools")
# devtools::install_github("mwheymans/psfmi") # for installing package
library(psfmi)
library(mice)

# Make reproducible data with 0 and 1 outcome variable
set.seed(123)
nhanes$hyp <- ifelse(nhanes$hyp==1,0,1)
nhanes$hyp <- as.factor(nhanes$hyp)

# Mice
imp <- mice(nhanes, m=5, maxit=5) 

nhanes_comp <- complete(imp, action = "long", include = FALSE)

pool_lr <- psfmi_lr(data=nhanes_comp, nimp=5, impvar=".imp", 
                    formula=hyp ~ bmi, method="D1")
pool_lr$RR_model
#> $`Step 1 - no variables removed -`
#>          term    estimate std.error   statistic       df   p.value        OR
#> 1 (Intercept) -0.76441322 3.4753113 -0.21995532 16.06120 0.8286773 0.4656071
#> 2         bmi -0.01262911 0.1302484 -0.09696177 15.79361 0.9239765 0.9874503
#>      lower.EXP upper.EXP
#> 1 0.0002947263 735.56349
#> 2 0.7489846190   1.30184

# Check performance
pool_performance(pool_lr, data = nhanes_comp, formula = hyp ~ bmi, 
                 nimp=5, impvar=".imp", 
                 cal.plot=TRUE, plot.indiv="mean", 
                 groups_cal=4, model_type="binomial")
#> Warning: argument plot.indiv is deprecated; please use plot.method instead.
```

[image]

```
#> $ROC_pooled
#>                     95% Low C-statistic 95% Up
#> C-statistic (logit)  0.2731      0.5207 0.7586
#> 
#> $coef_pooled
#> (Intercept)         bmi 
#> -0.76441322 -0.01262911 
#> 
#> $R2_pooled
#> [1] 0.009631891
#> 
#> $Brier_Scaled_pooled
#> [1] 0.004627443
#> 
#> $nimp
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> $HLtest_pooled
#>        F_value    P(>F) df1      df2
#> [1,] 0.9405937 0.400953   2 31.90878
#> 
#> $model_type
#> [1] "binomial"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This looks great, much cleaner than my self-made function! I don't think that this can be applied to an ordinal logistic regression, am I correct in this?

Answer (score 2):

When conducting logistic regression, I believe that it's good practice is to use [McFadden's](https://easystats.github.io/performance/reference/r2_mcfadden.html) or [Tjur's](https://easystats.github.io/performance/reference/r2_tjur.html) R2, since both of those tend to be used with generalized linear models. `mice::pool.r.squared` is designed to be only with `lm` models. [A previous StackOverflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65245547/using-mice-inputed-data-sets-in-glm-analysis-can-pooled-model-fit-indices-be-ob) had the same question as you and it seems that the best function for a multiply-imputed `glm()` model is `mfc()` from the Github package [`glmice`](https://github.com/noahlorinczcomi/glmice). The function [looks fairly simple](https://github.com/noahlorinczcomi/glmice/blob/master/R/mcf.R) and uses McFadden's R2, although the package hasn't been touched for a few years. That previous user wasn't able to get `mfc()` to work, but it worked for me.

```
# install.packages("remotes")
# remotes::install_github("noahlorinczcomi/glmice")
library(glmice)
library(mice)
data(nhanes)
nhanes$hyp <- ifelse(nhanes$hyp == 2, 1, 0)
imp <- mice(nhanes, m = 10, seed = 500, printFlag = FALSE)
mod <- with(imp, glm(hyp ~ age + bmi, family = "binomial"))
# summary(pool(mod))
mcf(mod)
#> [1] "34.9656%"
```

It looks like there are fewer resources on calculating AUC for a multiply-imputed `glm()`. I did find a [vignette from the `finalfit` package](https://finalfit.org/articles/missing.html), which calculated area under the curve. Unfortunately, it calculated AUC for each imputation. There might be a way to pool the output, but I'm not sure how (hopefully another SO user might suggest an idea?).

```
library(finalfit)
mod %>% 
  getfit() %>% 
  purrr::map(~ pROC::roc(.x$y, .x$fitted)$auc)
# not pasting the output because it's a lot
```

### small update

As of 1/23/23, I've noticed that the `glmice` Github page has been taken down. I'm posting the `mcf()` function here for reference.

```
#' Calculates McFadden's Pseudo R-Squared
#'
#' Returns McFadden's pseudo r-squared for logistic regression models performed on 'mice'-imputed data sets.
#' @param model a logit model from which you would like to return McFadden's pseudo r-squared. This can be a model created either with 'glm.mids()' or 'with()'
#' @return mcfs2: McFadden's pseudo r-squared
#' @export

mcf <- function (model) {
  iterations <- model$call1$m
  null_ds <- as.numeric()
  res_ds <- as.numeric()
  for (i in 1:iterations) {
    null_ds[i] <- model$analyses[[i]]$null.deviance
    res_ds[i] <- model$analyses[[i]]$deviance
  }
  ds <- cbind(as.numeric(null_ds), as.numeric(res_ds))
  m_null <- mean(null_ds)
  m_res <- mean(res_ds)
  mcfs <- round(((1 - (m_res / m_null)) * 100), 4)
  mcfs <- paste0(mcfs, "%")
  # end
  return(mcfs)
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you.the AUC is something I feel is common enough desire that someone will have forged a path before so hopefully someone will have a suggestion.